# HTML / CSS : hide overflow of fixed height div in pdf print

Tags: html, css, printing, overflow

EDIT: 
The problem seems to boil down to: Why don't pdfprinters properly read the CSS - and which ones do?

ORIGINAL POST:

I found many complaints about fixed height divs and printing but most people seem to have the opposite problem. I do want the overflow to NOT show in the printout. (Ideally adding a note, e.g. "etc.")

print.css

```
.myClass {
max-height:50px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

rep.html

```
<div class="myClass">86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008, ... </div>
```

The div contains a varying amount of numbers. I would like to create different print.css depending on whether the full information is needed, or examples suffice.

Firefox 36.0.4, Chrome 43.0.2357.124 m
tried with: Bullzip pdf printer, printpdf 0.76

This works fine for the browser view. But the (pdf) printed version always shows the full content of the div.

How can I hide the overflow in the pdf printout? overflow:hidden; does not work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Comment: It breaks page or cut it out ? please provide live code or some images.

Answer (score 0):

> ok, I think from html you provided you need to put the content of
>   `div(.myClass)` in tags as 
>   (`<p></p>`, `<pre></pre>`) and the content it has to be **more width** and **more height** then the **div(parent)** for example if the **div(parent)** `height:100px;` so the **height** for **child** it has to be more than `100px;` and the **width** as well too, like so in the
>   below

```css
 .myClass {
   width: 300px;
   max-height: 50px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <pre>86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008, ...</pre>
</div>
```

**If not try this code below:**

```css
.myClass {
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <pre>86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008,86777000, 8537681555608, 863831122008, 04317300008, ...</pre>
</div>
```

I hope this will work for you if not let me know below in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add ! important  `overflow:hidden !important`